# Vue i18n sometimes warn about missing key

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

In my home component I have the following:

```
const { location } = useLocation();
const { t, n } = useI18n();
const freeShippingValue = computed(() => {
  return n(100, 'currency', location.value);
});
```

In my BaseMoney component I have:

```
const { n } = useI18n();
const { location } = useLocation();
const formattedMoney = computed(() => {
  return n(amount.value, 'currency', location.value);
});
```

In Home.js this generates warnings:

```
[intlify] Not found 'currency' key in 'DE' locale messages.
[intlify] Fall back to number format 'currency' key with 'en-US' locale.
[intlify] Not found 'currency' key in 'en-US' locale messages.
[intlify] Not found 'currency' key in 'en-US' locale messages.
[intlify] Not found 'currency' key in 'en-US' locale messages.
[intlify] Fall back to number format 'currency' key with 'en' locale.
[intlify] Not found 'currency' key in 'en' locale messages.
[intlify] Fall back to number format 'currency' with root locale.
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/harm-meijer/spa3/tree/harm)

I set up i18n [here](https://github.com/harm-meijer/spa3/blob/harm/src/i18n.js) home is [here](https://github.com/harm-meijer/spa3/blob/harm/src/presentation/fashion/Home/Home.js) and BaseMoney is [here](https://github.com/harm-meijer/spa3/blob/harm/src/presentation/fashion/components/BaseMoney/BaseMoney.js)

Why would I get warnings in one component but not in another?

I can change both Home and BaseMoney to `return n(100, 'currency', 'US');` and still get a warning in Home but not in BaseMoney.

When I remove [translations for the component](https://github.com/harm-meijer/spa3/blob/harm/src/presentation/fashion/Home/Home.vue#L3) the warnings are not there but I don't understand why adding component translations breaks number formatting.

Comment: This is usually happens when define `en-US` and use `en`, try to be more consistent between config and usage, also I believe the language code is `en` (or `en-US`) rather than `US`.

Comment: Hi @HMR, had you solved it? I'm facing same problem.

Comment: @HMR I am also looking for an answer, found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I realized I used the `t` as `$t` in template. Fixed that and doesn't complain anymore.